# Multiple files function calls C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, function, include

I'm writing a program that calculates the norm of a vector (dot product with itself).
I have no problem implementing the code, what I can't do is call a function from a function other than the main one.

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER

void readArray(double [], int &);
void printArray(double [], int &);
void norm(double [], int &);
double scalarProduct(double [], int &);

#endif
```

norm.cc

```
// norm.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void norm(double array[], int & size)
{
    double norm;
    norm = sqrt(scalarProduct(array, size));

    cout << "Norm = " << norm << endl;
}
```

scalarProduct.cc

```
// scalarProduct.cc
#include <cmath>
double scalarProduct(double array[], int & size)
{
    double ps = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ps += pow(array[i], 2);
    }
}
```

in the main.cc file I added the line

```
#include "header.h"
```

and all the functions I call from main work like a charm, but calling productScalar() from norm() doesn't work. I added the same #include "header.h" line but the compiler says I can't define the same function more than once. How can I solve this?

Comment: You might wanna have a closer look at how OOP works : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: I wouldn't pass an `int` to a function as a reference if you do not alter its value.

Comment: That should work. Say what you mean by "doesn't work" and post the *exact* error message from the compiler. (BTW: You're forgetting to return anything from `scalarProduct` and why is the size parameter a reference?)

Comment: You forgot to return your result in `scalarProduct`.

Comment: Also norm.cc should have that `#include "header.h"`.

Comment: thanks for the heads up.. I added `#include "header.h"` as suggested and it works now.. must have done something wrong... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add
`#include "header.h"`
into norm.cc

Comment: thanks, it worked. I'm confused, because I'm sure I tried that, but the compiler would return the same error... I must have done something wrong.